# I an developing a blogging application, How can I insert media files like image,audio, video etc in my TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

```
Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        focusNode: titleFocusNode,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: titleFocusNode.hasFocus
                                  ? 24
                                  : 18.0, //I believe the size difference here is 6.0 to account padding
                              color: titleFocusNode.hasFocus
                                  ? Colors.orange
                                  : Colors.white),
                          labelText: 'Title',
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.black,
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                        maxLength: 100,
                        maxLines: null,
                        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                          FocusScope.of(context)
                              .requestFocus(titleFocusNode);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I wants to design an flutter application for blogging. I want to insert media files like audio, video, image files in the text form field. I have referred to many website but could not find anything. Please help me...

[This is what i want to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwu9F.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwu9F.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean by using a TextFormField that you want to insert the route of the media? If yes then you can trigger libraries like ImagePicker from the onTap property in the TextFormField to be activated when it's tapped and return the name of the media or even the path to it and place it in the field.

Comment: @BaselAbuhadrous I want to upload that media file in TextFormFeild.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, It's called a TEXT field, how do you want to upload media inside of it? walk me through the scenario you want to achieve

Comment: I want to insert image as well as text in my form field as we do in Quora and Medium. Now can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Flutter doesn't do this out of the box, but this doesn't mean it can't do it, what you need to do is to create code that understands that the text contains a image/media path inside of it, just like how stack overflow know how to differentiate between code, links and ordinary text, maybe [this](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_cap_text) plugin will help you get the idea, but it's not what you are looking for